# HTTP POST Request Popup Window

Tags: java, post, httpurlconnection

I am attempting to log into a website using Java's `HttpURLConnection`. I have figured out how to use a POST request to post to the website and log in, but I have no way of knowing if the login was successful or not.

Looking at some tutorials, I discerned that reloading the page usually works. The problem with this specific implementation is that upon entering credentials, the website opens a pop up window, with the same URL as the parent site.

This can be solved either of two ways. Looking at Chrome's Developer Tools, I realized that the POST request returns whether the login was successful, as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYscl.png)

Is it possible to get the popup window or look for the response to the POST request? I'd rather use native java is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Reload will work, if you'll keep the same HTTP session. Actually the website cannot open an popup - the web browser does it according to the login response. You should do the same - that is to check the response. Luckily you don't have to parse the response content, try to check the response code. For login the HTTP 200 may stand for successful login and HTTP 401 for failure.

Comment: For some reason even with incorrect credentials, the server returns a response code of 200